Inverse Laplace transform of product of three exponentials
Consider the Laplace Transform of the form
$$
\operatorname{F}\left(s\right) =
\frac{1}{\left(s - s_{1}\right)^{\large a_{1}}
\left(s - s_{2}\right)^{\large a_{2}}
\left(s - s_{3}\right)^{\large a_{3}}}
$$
where $a_1,a_2,a_3,s_1,s_2,s_3 \in \mathbb{R}^+$ are all positive given numbers.

Is it possible to calculate the Inverse transform $\operatorname {f}\left(t\right)$ ?.
If $a_1,a_2$ be integers it would be easy, however for real values I'm not sure if a closed form solution even exists !.
It is $0$ K if it can be expressed in terms of special function too.
I'm not sure about ROC ( any ROC that permits a solution would be $O$ K).
In general I guess if an inverse exists, it's ROC should be a left half plane !.

Any hints and references is welcome. Thanks in advance.

You have to solve HARD integral: $\int_0^t \frac{e^{\text{s1} (t-\tau )+\text{s1} \tau } (t-\tau )^{-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2}} \tau ^{-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2}} ,
_1F_1(\text{a2};\text{a1}+\text{a2};(-\text{s1}+\text{s2}) (t-\tau )) ,
_1F_1(\text{a2};\text{a1}+\text{a2};(-\text{s1}+\text{s2}) \tau )}{\Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2})^2} , d\tau$

To add a bit of context to the previous comment: It's not too hard to compute that the inverse Laplace transform of $(s-s')^{-a}$ is $e^{s' t}t^{a-1}/\Gamma(a)$. As such, we can use the convolution theorem to express the desired inverse Laplace transform as the convolution of three such functions. But while it's not too bad to convolve two of the three, convolving the result with the third is a good deal harder.

$\displaystyle\left(s - s_{k}\right)^{\large -a_{k}}$ has a branch-cut along $\displaystyle\left(-\infty, s_{k}\right]$ for $\displaystyle k = 1, 2, 3$. That makes the whole integration a monster one.

Ohhh joy! Unfortunately the conditions are as bad as I thought! Thanks for the hints guys! Existence of branch cut makes it impossible to use the contour integration and residue theorem, unfortunately, am I right? BTW solving the convolution integral in time domain (other than numerical) is impossible! The product of Confluent Hypergeometric functions does not permit a closed form!

From Tables of Inverse Laplace Transfrom:
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{(s-\text{s1})^{\text{a1}} (s-\text{s2})^{\text{a2}}}\right](t)=\\\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t+\frac{1}{2} (\text{s1}+\text{s2}) t}
   (\text{s1}-\text{s2})^{\frac{1}{2} (-\text{a1}-\text{a2})} t^{-1+\frac{\text{a1}+\text{a2}}{2}} ((\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t)^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} (-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2})} \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\text{a1}-\text{a2}}{2}+\frac{1}{2} (-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2});\text{a1}+\text{a2};(\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t\right)}{\Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2})}$$
using Mellin Transform for hypergeometric function 1F1 and remember that $A=1$,when using  Inverse Mellin.
$\mathcal{M}_A\left[\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t+\frac{1}{2} (\text{s1}+\text{s2}) t} (\text{s1}-\text{s2})^{\frac{1}{2} (-\text{a1}-\text{a2})}
   t^{-1+\frac{\text{a1}+\text{a2}}{2}} ((\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t)^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} (-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2})} \, _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\text{a1}-\text{a2}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}
   (-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2});\text{a1}+\text{a2};A (\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t\right)}{\Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2})}\right](q)=\\\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t+\frac{1}{2}
   (\text{s1}+\text{s2}) t} (\text{s1}-\text{s2})^{\frac{1}{2} (-\text{a1}-\text{a2})} t^{-1+\frac{\text{a1}+\text{a2}}{2}} ((\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t)^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}
   (-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2})} ((-\text{s1}+\text{s2}) t)^{-q} \Gamma (\text{a1}-q) \Gamma (q)}{\Gamma (\text{a1}) \Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2}-q)}$
using convolution theorem:
$\int_0^t \frac{\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} (\text{s1}-\text{s2}) (t-\tau )+\frac{1}{2} (\text{s1}+\text{s2}) (t-\tau )+\text{s3} \tau \right) (\text{s1}-\text{s2})^{\frac{1}{2}
   (-\text{a1}-\text{a2})} (t-\tau )^{-1+\frac{\text{a1}+\text{a2}}{2}} ((\text{s1}-\text{s2}) (t-\tau ))^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} (-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2})} ((-\text{s1}+\text{s2})
   (t-\tau ))^{-q} \tau ^{-1+\text{a3}} \Gamma (\text{a1}-q) \Gamma (q)}{\Gamma (\text{a1}) \Gamma (\text{a3}) \Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2}-q)} \, d\tau =\\\frac{e^{\text{s2} t}
   (-\text{s1}+\text{s2})^{-q} t^{-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}-q} \Gamma (\text{a1}-q) \Gamma (q) \, _1F_1(\text{a3};\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}-q;(-\text{s2}+\text{s3}) t)}{\Gamma
   (\text{a1}) \Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}-q)}$
and using Inverse Mellin Transform:
$$\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{\text{s2} t} (-\text{s1}+\text{s2})^{-q} t^{-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}-q} \Gamma (\text{a1}-q) \Gamma (q) \,
   _1F_1(\text{a3};\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}-q;(-\text{s2}+\text{s3}) t)}{\Gamma (\text{a1}) \Gamma
   (\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}-q)}\right](1)=\\\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{\text{s2} t} (-\text{s1}+\text{s2})^{-q} t^{-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}-q} \Gamma (\text{a1}-q)
   \Gamma (q) \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{((-\text{s2}+\text{s3}) t)^k (\text{a1})_k}{k! (\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}-q)_k}}{\Gamma (\text{a1}) \Gamma
   (\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}-q)}\right](1)=\\\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{\text{s2} t} (-\text{s1}+\text{s2})^{-q} t^{-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}-q}
   ((-\text{s2}+\text{s3}) t)^k \Gamma (\text{a1}+k) \Gamma (\text{a1}-q) \Gamma (q)}{\Gamma (\text{a1})^2 \Gamma (1+k) \Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}+k-q)}\right](1)=\\\sum
   _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{\text{s2} t} t^{-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}} ((-\text{s2}+\text{s3}) t)^k \Gamma (\text{a1}+k) \,
   _1F_1(\text{a1};\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}+k;(\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t)}{\Gamma (\text{a1}) \Gamma (1+k) \Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}+k)}=\\\frac{\left(e^{\text{s2} t}
   t^{-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}}\right) \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left((\text{a1})_j (\text{a3})_k\right) ((\text{s1}-\text{s2})
   t)^j ((-\text{s2}+\text{s3}) t)^k}{(\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3})_{j+k} j! k!}}{\Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3})}=\\\frac{\left(e^{\text{s2} t}
   t^{-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}}\right) \text{$\Phi $2}(\text{a1},\text{a2},\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3},(\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t,(-\text{s2}+\text{s3})
   t)}{\Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3})}$$
where: $\text{$\Phi $2}$ is Horn Function (I mean 17 series of two variables from the top)
The $\text{$\Phi $2}$ Horn Function can be expressed by Kampé de Fériet Function.
Mathematica code to compute a plot:
F[a1_, a2_, a3_, s1_, s2_, s3_, t_, M1_,  M2_] := (E^(s2 t) t^(-1 + a1 + a2 + a3))/Gamma[a1 + a2 + a3]* Sum[(Pochhammer[a1, j] Pochhammer[a3, k])/ Pochhammer[a1 + a2 + a3, j + k]*(((s1 - s2) t)^j)/ j! *(((-s2 + s3) t)^k)/k!, {j, 0, M1}, {k, 0, M2}] // N;  G[a1_, a2_, a3_, s1_, s2_, s3_, t_] :=  InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(s - s1)^a1*1/(s - s2)^a2 1/(s - s3)^a3, s, N@t]; Plot[{F[1/2, 1/3, 3/4, 1, 2, 3, t, 20, 20],  G[1/2, 1/3, 3/4, 1, 2, 3, t]}, {t, 10^-2, 2},  PlotStyle -> {Red, {Black, Dashed}},  PlotLegends -> {"Truncated Series", "Numeric Inverse Laplace"}]

Addition:
Inverse Laplace transform of product of four exponentials:
$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{(s-\text{s1})^{\text{a1}} (s-\text{s2})^{\text{a2}} (s-\text{s3})^{\text{a3}} (s-\text{s4})^{\text{a4}}}\right](t)=\\\frac{\left(e^{\text{s2} t}
   t^{-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}+\text{a4}}\right) \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left((\text{a1})_k (\text{a3})_m
   (\text{a3}+\text{a4})_{j+m}\right) \left(((\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t)^k ((\text{s3}-\text{s4}) t)^m ((-\text{s2}+\text{s4}) t)^j\right)}{\left((\text{a3}+\text{a4})_m
   (\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}+\text{a4})_{j+k+m}\right) (j! k! m!)}}{\Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}+\text{a4})}$
This infinte triple series can be expressed by Lauricella functions for 3 variables.

Thank you for this answer! I mean jeez, how did you get the idea to write it like this? BTW, could you please explain how did you get the expansion in the second line?

@K.K.McDonald All computation where  done in Mathematica, a powerfull software.

@MariuszIwaniuk Any numerical analysis/plots available?  I confess, I have a hard time grokking much from the formulas alone

@Mariusz Iwaniuk, wow, thank you! This was an eye opener. I mean I was completely hopeless about existence of any solution.

@Mariusz Iwaniuk sorry to bother you again, about the expansion of the second line that I asked in first comment, can you please give a hint where the sum $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{\text{s2} t} t^{-1+\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}} ((-\text{s2}+\text{s3}) t)^k \Gamma (\text{a3}+k) ,
_1F_1(\text{a1};\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}+k;(\text{s1}-\text{s2}) t)}{\Gamma (\text{a3}) \Gamma (1+k) \Gamma (\text{a1}+\text{a2}+\text{a3}+k)}$ comes from?

@K.K.McDonald I corrected my answer.

$\displaystyle +1$ for your incredible tour de force.

@FelixMarin Thanks a lot. May the force be with you. :)

@Mariusz Iwaniuk, thank you again! This answer is so complete it brings tears of joy to my tired old eyes ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ
